# How can I go over items in dictionary(key) in tcl?

Tags: tcl

```
puts "keys"
puts [dict keys $::db]
foreach file1 [dict get $::db files]
{
  puts $file1
}
```

I get an error:

keys
files
wrong # args: should be "foreach varList list ?varList list ...? command"
    while executing
"foreach file1 [dict get $::db files]"

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Tcl, you need to put the opening brace on the same line as the statement command:

```
foreach file1 [dict get $::db files] {
    puts $file1
}
```

Or you have to use backslashes:

```
foreach file1 [dict get $::db files] \
{
    puts $file1
}
```

But that's not something that you'll see being used often.

Comment: There used to be someone who contributed a lot to the Wiki who insisted on using backslashes like that in their code. It was _so_ ugly…